# What optimizations can GHC be expected to perform reliably?

Tags: optimization, haskell, ghc

GHC has a lot of optimizations that it can perform, but I don't know what they all are, nor how likely they are to be performed and under what circumstances.

My question is: what transformations can I expect it to apply every time, or nearly so? If I look at a piece of code that's going to be executed (evaluated) frequently and my first thought is "hmm, maybe I should optimize that", in which cases should my second thought be, "don't even think about it, GHC got this"?

I was reading the paper [Stream Fusion: From Lists to Streams to Nothing at All](http://metagraph.org/papers/stream_fusion.pdf), and the technique they used of rewriting list processing into a different form which GHC's normal optimizations would then reliably optimize down into simple loops was novel to me. How can I tell when my own programs are eligible for that kind of optimization?

There's [some information](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/options-optimise.html) in the GHC manual, but it only goes part of the way towards answering the question.

EDIT: I'm starting a bounty. What I would like is a list of lower-level transformations like lambda/let/case-floating, type/constructor/function argument specialization, strictness analysis and unboxing, worker/wrapper, and whatever else significant GHC does that I've left out, along with explanations and examples of input and output code, and ideally illustrations of situations when the total effect is more than the sum of its parts. And ideally some mention of when transformations *won't* happen. I'm not expecting novel-length explanations of every transformation, a couple of sentences and inline one-liner code examples could be enough (or a link, if it's not to twenty pages of scientific paper), as long as the big picture is clear by the end of it. I want to be able to look at a piece of code and be able to make a good guess about whether it will compile down to a tight loop, or why not, or what I would have to change to make it. (I'm not interested so much here in the big optimization frameworks like stream fusion (I just read a paper about that); more in the kind of knowledge that people who *write* these frameworks have.)

Comment: This is a most worthy question. Writing a worthy answer is... tricky.

Comment: A really good starting point is this: http://www.aosabook.org/en/ghc.html

Comment: In any language, if your first thought is "maybe I should optimize that," your second thought should be "I'll profile it first".

Comment: While the sort of knowledge you're after is helpful, and so this is still a good question, I think you're really better served by trying to do as *little* optimisation as possible. Write what you mean, and only when it becomes apparent that you need to *then* think about making the code less straightforward for the sake of performance. Rather than looking at code and thinking "that's going to be executed frequently, maybe I should optimise it", it should be only when you're observing code running too slowly that you think "I should find out what's executed frequently and optimise that".

Comment: I completely anticipated that part would call forth the exhortations to "profile it!" :). But I guess the other side of the coin is, if I profile it and it's slow, maybe I can rewrite or just tweak it into a form that's still high level but GHC can better optimize, instead of hand-optimizing it myself? Which requires the same kind of knowledge. And if I had had that knowledge in the first place I could have saved myself an edit-profile cycle.

Comment: I wish that the bounty had been offered to improve the answer on a Haskell wiki somewhere where it belongs and can be found again. That said, I tend to optimize Haskell code by careful timings and imagining what might be going on. I'm not sure how knowing I'm right could actually help, it's the timings themselves that matter.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

[This GHC Trac page](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/HscMain) also explains the passes fairly well. [This page](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/OptOrdering) explains the optimization ordering, though, like the majority of the Trac Wiki, it is out of date.

For specifics, the best thing to do is probably to look at how a specific program is compiled. The best way to see which optimizations are being performed is to compile the program verbosely, using the `-v` flag. Taking as an example the first piece of Haskell I could find on my computer:

```
Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 7.4.2, stage 2 booted by GHC version 7.4.1
Using binary package database: /usr/lib/ghc-7.4.2/package.conf.d/package.cache
wired-in package ghc-prim mapped to ghc-prim-0.2.0.0-7d3c2c69a5e8257a04b2c679c40e2fa7
wired-in package integer-gmp mapped to integer-gmp-0.4.0.0-af3a28fdc4138858e0c7c5ecc2a64f43
wired-in package base mapped to base-4.5.1.0-6e4c9bdc36eeb9121f27ccbbcb62e3f3
wired-in package rts mapped to builtin_rts
wired-in package template-haskell mapped to template-haskell-2.7.0.0-2bd128e15c2d50997ec26a1eaf8b23bf
wired-in package dph-seq not found.
wired-in package dph-par not found.
Hsc static flags: -static
*** Chasing dependencies:
Chasing modules from: *SleepSort.hs
Stable obj: [Main]
Stable BCO: []
Ready for upsweep
  [NONREC
      ModSummary {
         ms_hs_date = Tue Oct 18 22:22:11 CDT 2011
         ms_mod = main:Main,
         ms_textual_imps = [import (implicit) Prelude, import Control.Monad,
                            import Control.Concurrent, import System.Environment]
         ms_srcimps = []
      }]
*** Deleting temp files:
Deleting: 
compile: input file SleepSort.hs
Created temporary directory: /tmp/ghc4784_0
*** Checking old interface for main:Main:
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( SleepSort.hs, SleepSort.o )
*** Parser:
*** Renamer/typechecker:
*** Desugar:
Result size of Desugar (after optimization) = 79
*** Simplifier:
Result size of Simplifier iteration=1 = 87
Result size of Simplifier iteration=2 = 93
Result size of Simplifier iteration=3 = 83
Result size of Simplifier = 83
*** Specialise:
Result size of Specialise = 83
*** Float out(FOS {Lam = Just 0, Consts = True, PAPs = False}):
Result size of Float out(FOS {Lam = Just 0,
                              Consts = True,
                              PAPs = False}) = 95
*** Float inwards:
Result size of Float inwards = 95
*** Simplifier:
Result size of Simplifier iteration=1 = 253
Result size of Simplifier iteration=2 = 229
Result size of Simplifier = 229
*** Simplifier:
Result size of Simplifier iteration=1 = 218
Result size of Simplifier = 218
*** Simplifier:
Result size of Simplifier iteration=1 = 283
Result size of Simplifier iteration=2 = 226
Result size of Simplifier iteration=3 = 202
Result size of Simplifier = 202
*** Demand analysis:
Result size of Demand analysis = 202
*** Worker Wrapper binds:
Result size of Worker Wrapper binds = 202
*** Simplifier:
Result size of Simplifier = 202
*** Float out(FOS {Lam = Just 0, Consts = True, PAPs = True}):
Result size of Float out(FOS {Lam = Just 0,
                              Consts = True,
                              PAPs = True}) = 210
*** Common sub-expression:
Result size of Common sub-expression = 210
*** Float inwards:
Result size of Float inwards = 210
*** Liberate case:
Result size of Liberate case = 210
*** Simplifier:
Result size of Simplifier iteration=1 = 206
Result size of Simplifier = 206
*** SpecConstr:
Result size of SpecConstr = 206
*** Simplifier:
Result size of Simplifier = 206
*** Tidy Core:
Result size of Tidy Core = 206
writeBinIface: 4 Names
writeBinIface: 28 dict entries
*** CorePrep:
Result size of CorePrep = 224
*** Stg2Stg:
*** CodeGen:
*** CodeOutput:
*** Assembler:
'/usr/bin/gcc' '-fno-stack-protector' '-Wl,--hash-size=31' '-Wl,--reduce-memory-overheads' '-I.' '-c' '/tmp/ghc4784_0/ghc4784_0.s' '-o' 'SleepSort.o'
Upsweep completely successful.
*** Deleting temp files:
Deleting: /tmp/ghc4784_0/ghc4784_0.c /tmp/ghc4784_0/ghc4784_0.s
Warning: deleting non-existent /tmp/ghc4784_0/ghc4784_0.c
link: linkables are ...
LinkableM (Sat Sep 29 20:21:02 CDT 2012) main:Main
   [DotO SleepSort.o]
Linking SleepSort ...
*** C Compiler:
'/usr/bin/gcc' '-fno-stack-protector' '-Wl,--hash-size=31' '-Wl,--reduce-memory-overheads' '-c' '/tmp/ghc4784_0/ghc4784_0.c' '-o' '/tmp/ghc4784_0/ghc4784_0.o' '-DTABLES_NEXT_TO_CODE' '-I/usr/lib/ghc-7.4.2/include'
*** C Compiler:
'/usr/bin/gcc' '-fno-stack-protector' '-Wl,--hash-size=31' '-Wl,--reduce-memory-overheads' '-c' '/tmp/ghc4784_0/ghc4784_0.s' '-o' '/tmp/ghc4784_0/ghc4784_1.o' '-DTABLES_NEXT_TO_CODE' '-I/usr/lib/ghc-7.4.2/include'
*** Linker:
'/usr/bin/gcc' '-fno-stack-protector' '-Wl,--hash-size=31' '-Wl,--reduce-memory-overheads' '-o' 'SleepSort' 'SleepSort.o' '-L/usr/lib/ghc-7.4.2/base-4.5.1.0' '-L/usr/lib/ghc-7.4.2/integer-gmp-0.4.0.0' '-L/usr/lib/ghc-7.4.2/ghc-prim-0.2.0.0' '-L/usr/lib/ghc-7.4.2' '/tmp/ghc4784_0/ghc4784_0.o' '/tmp/ghc4784_0/ghc4784_1.o' '-lHSbase-4.5.1.0' '-lHSinteger-gmp-0.4.0.0' '-lgmp' '-lHSghc-prim-0.2.0.0' '-lHSrts' '-lm' '-lrt' '-ldl' '-u' 'ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Izh_static_info' '-u' 'ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Czh_static_info' '-u' 'ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Fzh_static_info' '-u' 'ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Dzh_static_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziPtr_Ptr_static_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziWord_Wzh_static_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziInt_I8zh_static_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziInt_I16zh_static_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziInt_I32zh_static_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziInt_I64zh_static_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziWord_W8zh_static_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziWord_W16zh_static_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziWord_W32zh_static_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziWord_W64zh_static_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziStable_StablePtr_static_info' '-u' 'ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Izh_con_info' '-u' 'ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Czh_con_info' '-u' 'ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Fzh_con_info' '-u' 'ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Dzh_con_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziPtr_Ptr_con_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziPtr_FunPtr_con_info' '-u' 'base_GHCziStable_StablePtr_con_info' '-u' 'ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_False_closure' '-u' 'ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_True_closure' '-u' 'base_GHCziPack_unpackCString_closure' '-u' 'base_GHCziIOziException_stackOverflow_closure' '-u' 'base_GHCziIOziException_heapOverflow_closure' '-u' 'base_ControlziExceptionziBase_nonTermination_closure' '-u' 'base_GHCziIOziException_blockedIndefinitelyOnMVar_closure' '-u' 'base_GHCziIOziException_blockedIndefinitelyOnSTM_closure' '-u' 'base_ControlziExceptionziBase_nestedAtomically_closure' '-u' 'base_GHCziWeak_runFinalizzerBatch_closure' '-u' 'base_GHCziTopHandler_flushStdHandles_closure' '-u' 'base_GHCziTopHandler_runIO_closure' '-u' 'base_GHCziTopHandler_runNonIO_closure' '-u' 'base_GHCziConcziIO_ensureIOManagerIsRunning_closure' '-u' 'base_GHCziConcziSync_runSparks_closure' '-u' 'base_GHCziConcziSignal_runHandlers_closure'
link: done
*** Deleting temp files:
Deleting: /tmp/ghc4784_0/ghc4784_1.o /tmp/ghc4784_0/ghc4784_0.s /tmp/ghc4784_0/ghc4784_0.o /tmp/ghc4784_0/ghc4784_0.c
*** Deleting temp dirs:
Deleting: /tmp/ghc4784_0
```

Looking from the first `*** Simplifier:` to the last, where all the optimization phases happen, we see quite a lot.

First of all, the Simplifier runs between almost all the phases. This makes writing many passes much easier. For example, when implementing many optimizations, they simply create rewrite rules to propagate the changes instead of having to do it manually. The simplifier encompasses a number of simple optimizations, including inlining and fusion. The main limitation of this that I know is that GHC refuses to inline recursive functions, and that things have to be named correctly for fusion to work.

Next, we see a full list of all the optimizations performed:

- Specialise

  The basic idea of specialization is to remove polymorphism and overloading by identifying places where the function is called and creating versions of the function that aren't polymorphic - they are specific to the types they are called with. You can also tell the compiler to do this with the `SPECIALISE` pragma. As an example, take a factorial function:

  ```
   fac :: (Num a, Eq a) => a -> a
   fac 0 = 1
   fac n = n * fac (n - 1)
  ```

  As the compiler doesn't know any properties of the multiplication that is to be used, it cannot optimize this at all. If however, it sees that it is used on an `Int`, it now can create a new version, differing only in the type:

  ```
   fac_Int :: Int -> Int
   fac_Int 0 = 1
   fac_Int n = n * fac_Int (n - 1)
  ```

  Next, rules mentioned below can fire, and you end up with something working on unboxed `Int`s, which is much faster than the original. Another way to look at specialisation is partial application on type class dictionaries and type variables.

  The [source](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/9.2.3/docs/html/libraries/ghc-9.2.3/src/GHC-Core-Opt-Specialise.html#specProgram) here has a load of notes in it.
- Float out

  EDIT: I apparently misunderstood this before. My explanation has completely changed.

  The basic idea of this is to move computations that shouldn't be repeated out of functions. For example, suppose we had this:

  ```
   \x -> let y = expensive in x+y
  ```

  In the above lambda, every time the function is called, `y` is recomputed. A better function, which floating out produces, is

  ```
   let y = expensive in \x -> x+y
  ```

  To facilitate the process, other transformations may be applied. For example, this happens:

  ```
    \x -> x + f 2
    \x -> x + let f_2 = f 2 in f_2
    \x -> let f_2 = f 2 in x + f_2
    let f_2 = f 2 in \x -> x + f_2
  ```

  Again, repeated computation is saved.

  The [source](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/9.2.3/docs/html/libraries/ghc-9.2.3/src/GHC-Core-Opt-FloatOut.html#floatOutwards) is very readable in this case.

  At the moment bindings between two adjacent lambdas are not floated. For example, this does not happen:

  ```
   \x y -> let t = x+x in ...
  ```

  going to

  ```
    \x -> let t = x+x in \y -> ...
  ```
- Float inwards

  Quoting the source code,

  The main purpose of `floatInwards` is floating into branches of a case, so that we don't allocate things, save them on the stack, and then discover that they aren't needed in the chosen branch.

  As an example, suppose we had this expression:

  ```
   let x = big in
       case v of
           True -> x + 1
           False -> 0
  ```

  If `v` evaluates to `False`, then by allocating `x`, which is presumably some big thunk, we have wasted time and space. Floating inwards fixes this, producing this:

  ```
   case v of
       True -> let x = big in x + 1
       False -> let x = big in 0
  ```

  , which is subsequently replaced by the simplifier with

  ```
   case v of
       True -> big + 1
       False -> 0
  ```

  [This paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/67060/float.ps.gz), although covering other topics, gives a fairly clear introduction. Note that despite their names, floating in and floating out don't get in an infinite loop for two reasons:

  1. Float in floats lets into `case` statements, while float out deals with functions.
  2. There is a fixed order of passes, so they shouldn't be alternating infinitely.
- Demand analysis

  Demand analysis, or strictness analysis is less of a transformation and more, like the name suggests, of an information gathering pass. The compiler finds functions that always evaluate their arguments (or at least some of them), and passes those arguments using call-by-value, instead of call-by-need. Since you get to evade the overheads of thunks, this is often much faster. Many performance problems in Haskell arise from either this pass failing, or code simply not being strict enough. A simple example is the difference between using `foldr`, `foldl`, and `foldl'` to sum a list of integers - the first causes stack overflow, the second causes heap overflow, and the last runs fine, because of strictness. This is probably the easiest to understand and best documented of all of these. I believe that polymorphism and CPS code often defeat this.
- Worker Wrapper binds

  The basic idea of the worker/wrapper transformation is to do a tight loop on a simple structure, converting to and from that structure at the ends. For example, take this function, which calculates the factorial of a number.

  ```
   factorial :: Int -> Int
   factorial 0 = 1
   factorial n = n * factorial (n - 1)
  ```

  Using the definition of `Int` in GHC, we have

  ```
   factorial :: Int -> Int
   factorial (I# 0#) = I# 1#
   factorial (I# n#) = I# (n# *# case factorial (I# (n# -# 1#)) of
       I# down# -> down#)
  ```

  Notice how the code is covered in `I#`s? We can remove them by doing this:

  ```
   factorial :: Int -> Int
   factorial (I# n#) = I# (factorial# n#)

   factorial# :: Int# -> Int#
   factorial# 0# = 1#
   factorial# n# = n# *# factorial# (n# -# 1#)
  ```

  Although this specific example could have also been done by SpecConstr, the worker/wrapper transformation is very general in the things it can do.
- Common sub-expression

  This is another really simple optimization that is very effective, like strictness analysis. The basic idea is that if you have two expressions that are the same, they will have the same value. For example, if `fib` is a Fibonacci number calculator, CSE will transform

  ```
   fib x + fib x
  ```

  into

  ```
   let fib_x = fib x in fib_x + fib_x
  ```

  which cuts the computation in half. Unfortunately, this can occasionally get in the way of other optimizations. Another problem is that the two expressions have to be in the same place and that they have to be *syntactically* the same, not the same by value. For example, CSE won't fire in the following code without a bunch of inlining:

  ```
   x = (1 + (2 + 3)) + ((1 + 2) + 3)
   y = f x
   z = g (f x) y
  ```

  However, if you compile via llvm, you may get some of this combined, due to its Global Value Numbering pass.
- Liberate case

  This seems to be a terribly documented transformation, besides the fact that it can cause code explosion. Here is a reformatted (and slightly rewritten) version of the little documentation I found:

  This module walks over `Core`, and looks for `case` on free variables. The criterion is: if there is a `case` on a free variable on the route to the recursive call, then the recursive call is replaced with an unfolding. For example, in

  ```
   f = \ t -> case v of V a b -> a : f t
  ```

  the inner `f` is replaced. to make

  ```
   f = \ t -> case v of V a b -> a : (letrec f = \ t -> case v of V a b -> a : f t in f) t
  ```

  Note the need for shadowing. Simplifying, we get

  ```
   f = \ t -> case v of V a b -> a : (letrec f = \ t -> a : f t in f t)
  ```

  This is better code, because `a` is free inside the inner `letrec`, rather than needing projection from `v`. Note that this deals with *free variables*, unlike SpecConstr, which deals with *arguments* that are of known form.

  See below for more information about SpecConstr.
- SpecConstr - this transforms programs like

  ```
   f (Left x) y = somthingComplicated1
   f (Right x) y = somethingComplicated2
  ```

  into

  ```
   f_Left x y = somethingComplicated1
   f_Right x y = somethingComplicated2

   {-# INLINE f #-}
   f (Left x) = f_Left x
   f (Right x) = f_Right x
  ```

  As an extended example, take this definition of `last`:

  ```
   last [] = error "last: empty list"
   last (x:[]) = x
   last (x:x2:xs) = last (x2:xs)
  ```

  We first transform it to

  ```
   last_nil = error "last: empty list"
   last_cons x [] = x
   last_cons x (x2:xs) = last (x2:xs)

   {-# INLINE last #-}
   last [] = last_nil
   last (x : xs) = last_cons x xs
  ```

  Next, the simplifier runs, and we have

  ```
   last_nil = error "last: empty list"
   last_cons x [] = x
   last_cons x (x2:xs) = last_cons x2 xs

   {-# INLINE last #-}
   last [] = last_nil
   last (x : xs) = last_cons x xs
  ```

  Note that the program is now faster, as we are not repeatedly boxing and unboxing the front of the list. Also note that the inlining is crucial, as it allows the new, more efficient definitions to actually be used, as well as making recursive definitions better.

  SpecConstr is controlled by a number of heuristics. The ones mentioned in the paper are as such:

  1. The lambdas are explicit and the arity is `a`.
  2. The right hand side is "sufficiently small," something controlled by a flag.
  3. The function is recursive, and the specializable call is used in the right hand side.
  4. All of the arguments to the function are present.
  5. At least one of the arguments is a constructor application.
  6. That argument is case-analysed somewhere in the function.

  However, the heuristics have almost certainly changed. In fact, the paper mentions an alternative sixth heuristic:

  Specialise on an argument `x` only if `x` is *only* scrutinised by a `case`, and is not passed to an ordinary function, or returned as part of the result.

This was a very small file (12 lines) and so possibly didn't trigger that many optimizations (though I think it did them all). This also doesn't tell you why it picked those passes and why it put them in that order.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere! Comments: You seem to have a cut-off sentence in the part about Specialise. I don't see the point of float-out: what is it for? How does it decide whether to float in or out (why doesn't it get into a loop)? I had the impression from somewhere that GHC didn't do CSE *at all*, but apparently that was mistaken. I feel like I'm getting lost in details instead of seeing a big picture... the topic is even more complicated than I thought. Maybe my question is impossible and there's just no way to gain this intuition except a ton of experience or working on GHC yourself?

Comment: Well, I don't know, but I've never worked on GHC, so you must be able to get *some* intuition.

Comment: I fixed the issues you mentioned.

Comment: Also, about the big picture, it is my opinion that there really isn't one. When I want to guess what optimizations will be performed, I go down a checklist. Then I do it again, to see how each pass will change things. And again. Essentially, I play the compiler. The only optimization scheme I know of that really has a "big picture" is supercompilation.

Comment: What do you mean by "things have to be named correctly for fusion to work" exactly?

Comment: That's one heck of an answer. Damn, I wanna go hack a compiler now!

Comment: This is a great answer! It's also slightly out of date, at least since the addition of [join points](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/SequentCore). Do you think you could update your answer, @gereeter?

Answer (score 67):

**Laziness**

It's not a "compiler optimisation", but it's something guaranteed by the language specification, so you can always count on it happening. Essentially, this means that work is not performed until you "do something" with the result. (Unless you do one of several things to deliberately turn off laziness.)

This, obviously, is an entire topic in its own right, and SO has lots of questions and answers about it already.

In my limited experience, making your code too lazy or too strict has *vastly* larger performance penalties (in time *and* space) than any of the other stuff I'm about to talk about...

**Strictness analysis**

Laziness is about avoiding work unless it's necessary. If the compiler can determine that a given result will "always" be needed, then it won't bother storing the calculation and performing it later; it'll just perform it directly, because that is more efficient. This is so-called "strictness analysis".

The gotcha, obviously, is that the compiler cannot *always* detect when something could be made strict. Sometimes you need to give the compiler little hints. (I'm not aware of any easy way to determine whether strictness analysis has done what you think it has, other than wading through the Core output.)

**Inlining**

If you call a function, and the compiler can tell which function you're calling, it may try to "inline" that function - that is, to replace the function call with a copy of the function itself. The overhead of a function call is usually pretty small, but inlining often enables other optimisations to happen which wouldn't have happened otherwise, so inlining can be a big win.

Functions are only inlined if they are "small enough" (or if you add a pragma specifically asking for inlining). Also, functions can only be inlined if the compiler can tell what function you're calling. There are two main ways that the compiler could be unable to tell:

- If the function you're calling is passed in from somewhere else. E.g., when the `filter` function is compiled, you can't inline the filter predicate, because it's a user-supplied argument.
- If the function you're calling is a class method *and* the compiler doesn't know what type is involved. E.g., when the `sum` function is compiled, the compiler can't inline the `+` function, because `sum` works with several different number types, each of which has a different `+` function.

In the latter case, you can use the `{-# SPECIALIZE #-}` pragma to generate versions of a function that are hard-coded to a particular type. E.g., `{-# SPECIALIZE sum :: [Int] -> Int #-}` would compile a version of `sum` hard-coded for the `Int` type, meaning that `+` can be inlined in this version.

Note, though, that our new special-`sum` function will only be called when the compiler can tell that we're working with `Int`. Otherwise the original, polymorphic `sum` gets called. Again, the actual function call overhead is fairly small. It's the additional optimisations that inlining can enable which are beneficial.

**Common subexpression elimination**

If a certain block of code calculates the same value twice, the compiler may replace that with a single instance of the same computation. For example, if you do

```
(sum xs + 1) / (sum xs + 2)
```

then the compiler might optimise this to

```
let s = sum xs in (s+1)/(s+2)
```

You might expect that the compiler would *always* do this. However, apparently in some situations this can result in worse performance, not better, so GHC does not *always* do this. Frankly, I don't really understand the details behind this one. But the bottom line is, if this transformation is important to you, it's not hard to do it manually. (And if it's not important, why are you worrying about it?)

**Case expressions**

Consider the following:

```
foo (0:_ ) = "zero"
foo (1:_ ) = "one"
foo (_:xs) = foo xs
foo (  []) = "end"
```

The first three equations all check whether the list is non-empty (among other things). But checking the same thing thrice is wasteful. Fortunately, it's very easy for the compiler to optimise this into several nested case expressions. In this case, something like

```
foo xs =
  case xs of
    y:ys ->
      case y of
        0 -> "zero"
        1 -> "one"
        _ -> foo ys
    []   -> "end"
```

This is rather less intuitive, but more efficient. Because the compiler can easily do this transformation, you don't have to worry about it. Just write your pattern matching in the most intuitive way possible; the compiler is very good at reordering and rearranging this to make it as fast as possible.

**Fusion**

The standard Haskell idiom for list processing is to chain together functions that take one list and produce a new list. The canonical example being

```
map g . map f
```

Unfortunately, while laziness guarantees skipping unecessary work, all the allocations and deallocations for the intermediate list sap performance. "Fusion" or "deforestation" is where the compiler tries to eliminate these intermediate steps.

The trouble is, most of these functions are recursive. Without the recursion, it would be an elementary exercise in inlining to squish all the functions into one big code block, run the simplifier over it and produce really optimal code with no intermediate lists. But because of the recursion, that won't work.

You can use `{-# RULE #-}` pragmas to fix some of this. For example,

```
{-# RULES "map/map" forall f g xs. map f (map g xs) = map (f.g) xs #-}
```

Now every time GHC sees `map` applied to `map`, it squishes it into a single pass over the list, eliminating the intermediate list.

Trouble is, this works only for `map` followed by `map`. There are many other possibilities - `map` followed by `filter`, `filter` followed by `map`, etc. Rather than hand-code a solution for each of them, so-called "stream fusion" was invented. This is a more complicated trick, which I won't describe here.

The long and short of it is: These are all special optimisation tricks written by *the programmer*. GHC itself knows nothing about fusion; it's all in the list librarys and other container libraries. So what optimisations happen depends on how your container libraries are written (or, more realistically, which libraries you choose to use).

For example, if you work with Haskell '98 arrays, don't expect any fusion of any kind. But I understand that the `vector` library has extensive fusion capabilities. It's all about the libraries; the compiler just provides the `RULES` pragma. (Which is extremely powerful, by the way. As a library author, you can use it to rewrite client code!)

---

Meta:

- I agree with the people saying "code first, profile second, optimise third".
- I also agree with the people saying "it is useful to have a mental model for how much cost a given design decision has".

Balance in all things, and all that...

Comment: `it's something guaranteed by the language specification ... work is not performed until you "do something" with the result.` - not exactly. The language spec promises *non-strict semantics*; it does not promise anything about whether or not superfluous work will be performed.

Comment: @DanBurton Sure. But that's not real easy to explain in a few sentences. Besides, since GHC is almost the only extant Haskell implementation, the fact that GHC is lazy is good enough for most people.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid: speculative evaluations is an interesting counterexample, although I'd agree it's probably too much for a beginner.

Comment: About CSE: My impression is that it is done almost never, because it can introduce unwanted sharing and hence spaceleaks.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner I'd be interested in seeing a fuller exploration of this idea - but this comment thread is probably not the right place.

Comment: Sorry for (a) not replying before now and (b) not accepting your answer. Which is long and impressive, but doesn't cover the territory I wanted. What I would like is a list of lower-level transformations like lambda/let/case-floating, type/constructor/function argument specialization, strictness analysis and unboxing (which you mention), worker/wrapper, and whatever else GHC does, along with explanations and examples of input and output code, and ideally examples of their combined effect and ones where the transformations *don't* happen. I guess I should make a bounty?

Comment: @illissius That sounds like something that's going to be too large for an SO answer. I admit it also sounds like it would be pretty interesting...

Comment: I'm not sure it would be. A couple sentences explanation and inline one-liner code examples per transformation could be enough, as long as the big picture by the end is clear.

Answer (score 8):

If a let binding v = rhs is used in only one place you can count on the compiler to inline it, even if rhs is big.

The exception (that almost isn't one in the context of the current question) is lambdas risking work duplication. Consider:

```
let v = rhs
    l = \x-> v + x
in map l [1..100]
```

there inlining v would be dangerous because the one (syntactic) use would translate into 99 extra evaluations of rhs. However, in this case, you would be very unlikely to want to inline it manually either. So essentially you can use the rule:

If you'd consider inlining a name that only appears once, the compiler will do it anyway.

As a happy corollary, using a let binding simply to decompose a long statement (with hope of gaining clarity) is essentially free.

This comes from 
community.haskell.org/~simonmar/papers/inline.pdf
which includes a lot more information about inlining.