# How can I get at the cleverest optimizations that GHC makes?

Tags: haskell, optimization, ghc, compiler-optimization

Because I can see it coming: this is a different question than [What optimizations can GHC be expected to perform reliably?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653787/what-optimizations-can-ghc-be-expected-to-perform-reliably) because I'm not asking for the most reliable optimizations, just the most clever/powerful.

I'm specifically looking for *non-intuitive* optimizations that GHC makes that can have serious impacts on performance and demonstrate the power of compiler optimizations *related to lazy evaluation or purity.* And direct explanations about how to get at them.

The best answers will have:

- An explanation of the optimization and *why it is so clever or powerful*
- Why the optimization improves performance
- How GHC recognizes when it can use this optimization
- *What the optimization actually transforms the code into*
- Why this optimization requires lazy evaluation or purity

Comment: I've added lots of specificity on the kinds of answers I want and exactly what I'm looking for. What else should I add to make this less broad?

Comment: However many limitations you add, this is by its very nature a free-for-all open ended question which has no one particular answer.

Comment: @deceze: I faved this question, but I am not voting for reopen, because of the exact reason you mention.

Comment: @deceze: But this is true of several other questions, like the one I linked to, which remained open.

Comment: @sortfiend StackOverflow (and other SE sites) are generally unfriendly to "big list" questions. See e.g. [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366) for why.

Comment: @DanielWagner Maybe if I rephrase to asking how to get at the cleverest/best GHC optimizations?

Comment: Changed the question to make it less "listy" and more specifically applicable.

Comment: @phresnel I changed the structure of the question, so it is less of a free-for-all.

Comment: I think it is still too broad. "Best" is highly subjective and depends on a particular code-section and its full context.

Answer (score 3):

Stream fusion is probably the biggest one. It turns something like `sum . map (+1) . filter (>5)`, which nominally allocates two new lists, into a simple loop that operates in constant space.

Comment: However, that's not a `ghc` optimization, but actually a library optimization implemented as a set of rewrite rules.  The compiler has no built-in support for optimizing lists using fusion.